# Loading external resources in a basic web browser

Tags: javascript, browser, fetch-api, cors-anywhere

As part of a coding challenge that I came up with, I am building a basic web browser PURELY in `html` and `javascript` that can run on a host browser as a `data uri`. My code is as follows:

```
data:text/html,<head><title>Basic Web Browser</title></head>
<h1>Basic Web Browser</h1>
Enter Web Address or search terms: <input id="url" type="text"/><input type="button" value="Go" onclick="view();"/><input type="button" onclick="textsearch()" value="Google Search"/><input type="button" onclick="imagesearch()" value="Image Search"/><input type="button" value="Open Google URL" onclick="googleURL();"/><input type="button" value="Edit links" onclick="edit()" id="edit" style="display:none"/><input type="button" value="Iframe" onclick="iframe()"/>&nbsp;<a target="_blank">New Tab</a><br/></p><p style="display:none"><script>window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
    alert('JavaScript error: ' + message + ' on line ' + linenumber + ' for ' + url);
};</script><script>
document.querySelector('a').href = window.location;
function iframe() {
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML='<iframe src="' + document.getElementById('url').value + '" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>';
};
function textsearch() {
  document.getElementById('url').value = 'google.com/search?q=' + document.getElementById('url').value;
  view();
};
function imagesearch() {
  document.getElementById('url').value = 'google.com/images?q=' + document.getElementById('url').value;
  view();
};
function redirect() {
  document.getElementById('url').value = this.href;
  view();
  return false;
};
var getLocation = function(href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l;
};
function edit() {
  for (var i = 0; i < Array.from(document.querySelector('div').querySelectorAll('a')).length; i++) {
    var tempURL = Array.from(document.querySelector('div').querySelectorAll('a'))[i];
    var tempURLEntered = document.getElementById('url').value;
    if (tempURLEntered.slice(0,4) != 'http') {
      tempURLEntered = 'http://' + tempURLEntered;
    };
    if (getLocation(tempURL).hostname.length == 0 && tempURL.href.slice(0,4) != 'data') {
      tempURL.href = 'http://' + getLocation(tempURLEntered).hostname + tempURL.href;
    };
    if (tempURL.onclick == null) {
      tempURL.onclick = redirect;
    } else {
      tempURL.onclick = ';redirect()';
    };
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < Array.from(document.querySelector('div').querySelectorAll('img')).length; i++) {
    var tempURL = Array.from(document.querySelector('div').querySelectorAll('img'))[i];
    alert(tempURL.src);
    var tempURLEntered = document.getElementById('url').value;
    if (tempURLEntered.slice(0,4) != 'http') {
      tempURLEntered = 'http://' + tempURLEntered;
    };
    if (getLocation(tempURL.src).hostname.length == 0 && tempURL.src.slice(0,4) != 'data') {
      tempURL.src = 'https://' + getLocation(tempURLEntered).hostname + tempURL.src;
    };
    alert(tempURL.src);
  };
  document.getElementById('edit').style='display:none';
};
function googleURL() {
  url = decodeURIComponent(url).slice(decodeURIComponent(url).indexOf('url')+6,decodeURIComponent(url).indexOf('sa')-1);
  document.getElementById('url').value = url;
  view();
}
function parse(data) {
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = data;
  edit();
  document.getElementById('edit').style='';
  alert(Array.from(document.querySelector('div').querySelectorAll('img')));
};
function view() { 
var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
if (url.slice(18,21) == 'url') {
url = decodeURIComponent(url).slice(decodeURIComponent(url).indexOf('url')+6,decodeURIComponent(url).indexOf('sa')-1);
document.getElementById('url').value = url;
}
fetch('https://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com/' + url).then((response) => response.text()).then((text) => parse(text));
};
</script>
<div allowfullscreen></div>
```

Please excuse my sloppy code. Anyways, this basic web browser works in iOS Safari, Mozilla Firefox, and Google Chrome. However, the issue occurs when a website attempts to load an external resource. If I have an `<img/>` tag, for example, and the image source is `/the/path/to/image.png`, my basic web browser does not know where to look for that image. I attempt to fix this issue with my `edit()` function, but it does not work very efficiently. Plus, my `edit()` function can only deal with *some* links and images, other tags and JavaScript are completely ignored. So how can I change my basic web browser so that other tags and JavaScript can refer to external resources? Please feel free to recommend modifications to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve relative URLs with the base url of the address that's being opened. If you look at the documentation of `new URL()` you see that you can specify a second base URL. Pass the relative url from the image as the first argument, and the absolute url of the current document you have open as the second.